# Network connectivity iPhone Reachability class buggy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, networking

Ok so I am trying to check for internet connectivity as my app requires it, I have included the reachability.h files as a solution suggested here [Easiest way to determine whether iPhone internet connection is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784582/easiest-way-to-determine-whether-iphone-internet-connection-is-available) but I am getting 12 errors from that class. Any suggestions

[image: errors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as importing `reachability.h`, you also need to add the System Configuration framework to your project?

[image]