# iphone:How to check each & every time internet connection in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hello friends,
             I want to check internet connection each & every time is active or not in my iPhone apps so please tell me any link or any idea to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Reachability` Classes

```
+ (BOOL)isNetworkAvailable {

    Reachability *internetReach;
    internetReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReach startNotifier];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [internetReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(netStatus == NotReachable) { 
        NSLog(@"Network Unavailable");
        return NO;
    }
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Nikunj, Just a tip: Adding dots after "Thanks a lot" makes it sound a bit sarcastic :p

Answer (score 0):

```
//check for internet connection
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSError *error;
NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"] usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
    if (connected == nil) {
        //no internet connection..display alert
    } else {
       //call your function
    }
```

This should help you.

Comment: This would dalay and if internet is not reachable the thread will stop for around 30 seconds. This is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reachability example from apple [developer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

I use it like this:

```
-(BOOL) isInternetReachable 
{
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You can also check to see if a certain server is up with the provided methods.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [**Reachability Class**](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/) and also [go through...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784582/easiest-way-to-determine-whether-iphone-internet-connection-is-available)