# How to detect device IP address change on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, tcp

Is this even possible? I couldn't find code on how to do it. When not on Wi-Fi, the device IP keeps changing, & I need to keep track of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Rechability](https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-ios-programming-alasdair-allan-2nd/chapter-7/detecting-network-status) and schedule some timer to check whether any change occurred. It will looks like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652465/capture-wi-fi-network-changing-event-in-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098956/how-to-detect-change-in-network-with-reachability).

For retrieving IP address you can try [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700809/3151066).

If possible test with a real device not a simulator as it probably will not be working properly on the simulator (once I tested sth similar and it failed on the simulator while worked perfectly fine on the real devices).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that is possible directly, but using Reachability to catch every network reconnect you can get new ip each time.